# Apollo useQuery how to assert query haveBeenCalled?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, apollo-client, react-apollo

I am trying to assert a if a specific query was called n times using MockProvider.
Tried also **jest.spyOn<any, any>(useQuery, 'default')**

```
jest.mock('@apollo/client', () => {
  return {
    ...jest.requireActual('@apollo/client'),
    useQuery: () => jest.fn,
  };
 });

const mountComponent = () => {
  return render(
    <MockedProvider mocks={mocks} addTypename={false}>
      <MyComponent />
    </MockedProvider>
  );
};

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  it('should only call the query 1 time', async () => {
    mountComponent();

    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(useQuery).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
  });
});
```

Jest error log:

```
Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function

Received has type:  function
Received has value: [Function bound fn]
```

Answer (score 0):

You assign an anonymous function instead of the mock function to `useQuery`. It should be:

```
jest.mock('@apollo/client', () => {
  return {
    ...jest.requireActual('@apollo/client'),
    useQuery: jest.fn(),
  };
});
```